# How to solve ProviderManifestToken="8.3.7" and Npgsql ProviderManifestToken="8.1.3" conflict?

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to connect to my PostgreSQL database using Entity Framework. Unfortunately after generating a model using EdmGen (or EdmGen2) in my SSDL file ProviderManifestToken is set to 8.3.7 when in the current version of Npgsql (2.0.9) it is set to 8.1.3. This gives me fallowing exception when trying to use my entity model:

> System.Data.MetadataException: Schema
>   specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlSchema.ssdl(2,52) : error
>   0169: All SSDL artifacts must target
>   the same provider. The
>   ProviderManifestToken '8.1.3' is
>   different from '8.3.7' that was
>   encountered earlier.

Any ideas how to fix it or generate a model with ProviderManifestToken eq 8.1.3?

Please don't suggest commercial database connectors my budget won't allow it :P

Comment: I'm missing something, here. Why not just change it to the correct value? Does something break when you do?

Comment: Yes. I get: Exception Details: System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
error 0194: All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered.
Probably I would need to change some of the schemas definitions - but I don't know what exactly :/

Answer (score 2):

- Open your edmx file in a text editor.
- Look for the *ProviderManifestToken* attribute of the
  *Edmx/Runtime/StorageModels/Schema* element.
- If it is set to 8.1.3, change it to 8.3.7 and then recompile everything.